# Add image in highcharts labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, highcharts

I am trying to draw Highchart and placing image and text on slices. But somehow SVG image is not getting displayed.

Below is the Fiddle link

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/mo8dfztx/3/)

Some of the code i am using to display image in Series object is

```
formatter : function(){
            return '<svg class="icon">
                    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="red"  /></svg> 7 
                    %'  ; 
},
```

Comment: Note that rendering SVG in SVG will render tooltip below that dataLabels. You will need to set `useHTML` for tooltip too (using answer by @faraz) and set all background/border/shadows in CSS instead of Highcharts defaults. Example of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/mo8dfztx/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highchart's default rendering uses SVGs text nodes, which only render text. You'll need to force the labels to use HTML:

```
dataLabels:{
    useHTML: true,
    formatter : function(){
         return '<svg class="icon"><circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="red"  /></svg> 7 %'  ; 
    },
}
```

Note this will cause some pretty wacky rendering, so you'll need to adjust the CSS accordingly.

Comment: my concern is now same.. i want labels to be exactly in center of each slice having icon.. kindly suggest

Comment: i accepted this as answer as this solves the image issue but still centering it on each Slice is not solved

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't have the time to dig into that. Hopefully this helped move you further along.